# 1 Corinthians 13:10 - What does Paul mean by "Completeness"?

Tags: word-study, 1-corinthians, paul, spiritual-gifts, cessationism

**What are the meanings given the original Greek word?**

> [NIV, 1 Corinthians 13:8-10](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2013:8-10&version=NIV) - Love never fails. But where there are prophecies, they will cease; where there are tongues, they will be stilled; where there is knowledge, it will pass away. For we know in part and we prophesy in part, but when ***[completeness  | τὸ τέλειον](http://biblehub.com/text/1_corinthians/13-10.htm)*** comes, what is in part disappears.

This verse is often used as a basis for cessationism, which argues that completeness came at the end of the apostolic age. Is this what Paul was intending?

This passage appears in a discussion on the nature of love, what is the meaning of completeness given the context of this discussion?

<sup>***Closely Related To:***

- [1 Corinthians 13:10 - What does "The Perfect" Refer to?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/18828/1-corinthians-1310-what-does-the-perfect-refer-to)

- [1 Corinthians 13:10 - Should "The Perfect" Be Interpreted in an Eschatological Sense?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/1-corinthians-1310-when-does-the-perfect-actually-come)

- [1 Corinthians 13:10 - What Will Cease when "The Perfect" Comes?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23615/1-corinthians-1310-what-will-cease-when-the-perfect-comes)

- [1 Corinthians 13:8 - What is the Significance of the Intransitive verb "παύσονται"?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/22062/1-corinthians-138-what-is-the-significance-of-the-intransitive-verb-%CF%80%CE%B1%CF%8D%CF%83%CE%BF%CE%BD%CF%84%CE%B1)

- [1 Corinthians 13:9-10 - What Does "ἐκ μέρους" Mean?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/19589/1-corinthians-139-10-what-does-%E1%BC%90%CE%BA-%CE%BC%CE%AD%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%85%CF%82-mean)

- [1 Corinthians 13:9 - How Should "Out Of" Be Translated?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/23597/1-corinthians-139-what-does-out-from-mean)</sup>

Comment: Interesting.  I had always assumed the passage was clearly referring to the resurrection - I had never heard the cessationist position before.

Comment: @Jas3.1 I'm not sure it's fair to call that "the cessation position". Yes this verse gets cited by a lot of cessationists in support of their position, but many others (myself included) will cringe at that handling of this verse even if they agree with the gist of the position.

Comment: The word "comes" after the word completeness is missing, its insertion will give the verse a slightly different meaning. Please add.

Answer (score 6):

### τέλειος

The word Paul used that's translated "completeness" is:

> *teleios* <[5046](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=5046)>
>
> 1) brought to its end, finished
>   2) wanting nothing necessary to completeness
>   3) perfect
>   4) that which is perfect
>   4a) consummate human integrity and virtue
>   4b) of men
>   4b1) full grown, adult, of full age, mature

To as student of philosophy, as I believe both Paul and the [Corinthians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_Greece) were, the word naturally would be connected to [teleology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleology), the study of the final cause or purpose of things.  Paul contrasts it with the "partial" (*meros* <[3313](http://classic.net.bible.org/strong.php?id=3313)>), which will pass away.  According to the [*Theological Dictionary of the New Testament, Volume 1*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ltZBUW_F9ogC), there's a philosophical angle to μέρος as well:

> The LXX does not use it for human or animal parts of the body, but Philo has it in this sense, as well as for parts of the soul or the world. Accepting the unity of the cosmos, Philo teaches the Stoic harmony of the parts.  The parts share in the totality only for the sake of the totality, and the truly perfect good is a whole.  As a  part, man cannot be the direct image of God, only an image of the *logos*.—p. 585

---

Chapter 13 is sandwiched between two parts of Paul's instructions on spiritual gifts.  Chapter 12 addresses the problem that different people get different gifts, which apparently caused dissension among the believers in Corinth.  Paul pulls out one of his favorite analogies: the church as a body with a variety of members.  He transitions to his [definition of love](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/950/68):

> But earnestly desire the higher gifts.
>   And I will show you a still more excellent way.—1<sup>st</sup> Corinthians 12:31 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/1+Corinthians+12/))

The "still more excellent way", therefore is *agape* love.  It is a power that brings the parts together and provides the ultimate purpose for the spiritual gifts.  So Paul follows Philo's argument that as individual parts, we aren't yet direct images of God.  So, when will that happen?  When will we see "face to face"?

The passage lists several things that will cease:

1. prophesies
2. tongues
3. knowledge (*gnōsis* <[1108](http://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1108)>)

The easiest reading is that knowledge will pass away at some point in the future when we have direct communication with God.  Prophesies and tongues as specialized gifts provided to communicate with other believers would also be unnecessary at that point in the future. Therefore, the cessationist, must argue that somehow knowledge has also come to an end.

### Conclusion

Since I can't think of a plausible argument for why knowledge might continue after other spiritual gifts have ceased, I believe this passage must be looking forward to the future when Jesus will return and the church will meet Him in person.

Answer (score 1):

1 Corinthians 13 is often called the "love chapter" but his theme is actually teaching about the utilitarian nature of the gifts vs the enduring intrinsic value of love. He compares the gifts to children's toys fit only for children:

> NIV 1 Cor 13:11 When I was a child, I talked like a child, I thought
>   like a child, I reasoned like a child. When I became a man, I put the
>   ways of childhood behind me.

Exercising a gift with no benevolent purpose is merely noise, like banging a drum for no particular purpose and that no one wants to hear:

> NIV 1 Cor 13: <sup>1</sup>If I speak in the tongues of men or of angels, but do not have love, I am only a resounding gong or a clanging cymbal. <sup>2</sup>If I have the gift of prophecy and can fathom all mysteries and all knowledge, and if I have a faith that can move mountains, but do not have love, I am nothing. <sup>3</sup>If I give all I possess to the poor and give over my body to hardship that I may boast, but do not have love, I gain nothing.

So to get up in a meeting and to start speaking mysteries in Korean when no one in the room speaks Korean is just silliness and rudeness:

> NIV 1 Cor 14: <sup>1</sup>Follow the way of love and eagerly desire gifts of the Spirit, especially prophecy. <sup>2</sup>For anyone who speaks in a tongue does not speak to people but to God. Indeed, no one understands them; they utter mysteries by the Spirit. <sup>3</sup>But the one who prophesies speaks to people for their strengthening, encouraging and comfort. <sup>4</sup>Anyone who speaks in a tongue edifies themselves, but the one who prophesies edifies the church. <sup>5</sup>I would like every one of you to speak in tongues, but I would rather have you prophesy. The one who prophesies is greater than the one who speaks in tongues, unless someone interprets, so that the church may be edified.
>   <sup>6</sup>Now, brothers and sisters, if I come to you and speak in tongues, what good will I be to you, unless I bring you some revelation or knowledge or prophecy or word of instruction? <sup>7</sup>Even in the case of lifeless things that make sounds, such as the pipe or harp, how will anyone know what tune is being played unless there is a distinction in the notes? <sup>8</sup>Again, if the trumpet does not sound a clear call, who will get ready for battle? <sup>9</sup>So it is with you. Unless you speak intelligible words with your tongue, how will anyone know what you are saying? You will just be speaking into the air. <sup>10</sup>Undoubtedly there are all sorts of languages in the world, yet none of them is without meaning. <sup>11</sup>If then I do not grasp the meaning of what someone is saying, I am a foreigner to the speaker, and the speaker is a foreigner to me. <sup>12</sup>So it is with you. Since you are eager for gifts of the Spirit, try to excel in those that build up the church.
>   <sup>13</sup>For this reason the one who speaks in a tongue should pray that they may interpret what they say. <sup>14</sup>For if I pray in a tongue, my spirit prays, but my mind is unfruitful. <sup>15</sup>So what shall I do? I will pray with my spirit, but I will also pray with my understanding; I will sing with my spirit, but I will also sing with my understanding. <sup>16</sup>Otherwise when you are praising God in the Spirit, how can someone else, who is now put in the position of an inquirer,d say “Amen” to your thanksgiving, since they do not know what you are saying? <sup>17</sup>You are giving thanks well enough, but no one else is edified.
>    <sup>18</sup>I thank God that I speak in tongues more than all of you. <sup>19</sup>But in the church I would rather speak five intelligible words to instruct others than ten thousand words in a tongue.
>   <sup>20</sup>Brothers and sisters, stop thinking like children. In regard to evil be infants, but in your thinking be adults.

Prophetic gifts will become irrelevant in the eschaton because the saints will no longer be walking by faith (in the unseen) but rather by sight (in whom they see):

> BSB 1 Corinthians 13: <sup>11</sup>When I was a child, I talked like a child, I thought like a child, I reasoned like a child. When I became a man, I set aside  childish ways. <sup>12</sup>Now we see but a dim reflection as in a  mirror; then we shall see face to face. Now I know in part; then I shall know fully, even as I am fully known. <sup>13</sup>And now these three remain: faith, hope, and love; but the greatest of these is love.

So in the immediate context the "completeness" to come is in the eschaton.

Answer (score 1):

τὸ τέλειον at verse 10, refer to πρόσωπον (face, presence) at verse 12.

πρόσωπον neuter singular. πρόσωπον is translated as: 1. face (Matt 17:2, Mark 1:2, 1 Peter 3:2, etc), 2. presence (Acts 3:19, Acts 5:41, 2 Th 1:9, etc).

The complete face (presence) of Jesus Christ.

2 Corinthians 4:6

For God, who commanded the light to shine out of darkness, hath shined in our hearts, to give the light of the knowledge of the glory of God in THE FACE OF JESUS CHRIST.

Face to face. We will look at the complete face (presence) of Jesus Christ, and will have the complete knowledge of the glory of God. No more "I know in part".

Answer (score 0):

**Complete/τὸ τέλειον.**

**Paul said in  verse 9 " For we know in part and we prophesy in part."**

The  gifts of prophesy which  God gave his prophets  the power to make new prophesies , and give us new knowledge were   in " part  ".  These prophesies in other words  did not give us full details of the future will and purpose of God for mankind ,and further prophesies were required and given, until the full  knowledge was complete concerning  that which was prophesied.

Now that the Word of God is **complete/τὸ τέλειον**, we have all the prophesies and knowledge required for our salvation, so the gifts of prophesies, tongues and knowledge are no longer required, and have therefore been done away with.

Answer (score 0):

What are the meaning of the original Greek word?

Perfect, according to Bible hud Strongs concordance, 5046 is  τέλειος/ teleios and it’s an adjective.
teleios: having reached its end, i.e. complete, by ext. perfect

Depending on the context, according to Bible hub Strongs concordance, Teleios/perfect can mean (a) complete in all its parts, (b) full grown, of full age, (c) specially of the completeness of Christian character.

1 corinthians 13: 8Charity never faileth: but whether there be prophecies, they shall fail; whether there be tongues, they shall cease; whether there be knowledge, it shall vanish away. 9For we know in part, and we prophesy in part. 10But when that which is perfect is come, then that which is in part shall be done away. 11When I was a child, I spake as a child, I understood as a child, I thought as a child: but when I became a man, I put away childish things. 12For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known. 13And now abideth faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity.

#1 What does the perfect refer to?
In light of these gifts: Prophecy, Knowledge and Tongues; the perfect τέλειος/teleios, cessationist say that it means the Bible/New Testament.
Nevertheless, verse 13, “And now abideth faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity”; the now is charity/love.
Therefore, the perfect is not the New testament because the perfect comes in the future.

1 corinthians 1:7 “so as for you not to be lacking in any gift…” We, and the Corinthians, had/have all the gifts χάρισμα/charisma, all the spiritual endowments or gifts which are available to us by the Lord’s grace and the Spirit of God who gives them; some Christians may have this gift or that gift even may have more than one gift, accordingly to the Spirit’s will (1 Corinthians 12:7-11); Lord parable on the talents: Matthew 25:14-30 Luke 19:11-27.

However, we are, continuing verse 7 “…eagerly await the revelation of our Lord Jesus Christ” (BLB). Thus, that Perfect come is the Lord Jesus Christ when he appears for the 2nd Advent or Coming.
Thus, the Perfect refers to Christ.

#2 should the perfect be interpreted in an Eschatological sense?
Yes, the perfect should be understood in an Eschatological sense for when that which is perfect is come,
Notice, verse 10, when that which is perfect is come; the Perfect has not come yet, it is future.
Look at verse 12, the for now and the then; now is at present to our time; the then takes place when verse 10 that perfect comes, Christ 2nd Advent.
for now we see through a glass darkly; but then face to face. This proves the perfect is a Person not the Bible/New Testament.

#3 What will cease when the perfect comes?
Verse 10, then that which is in part shall be done away: the knowledge, prophecy and tongues; we have no need for these parts, for we shall have the completion of all things here with us. When we are face-to-face with our Lord, Jesus Christ, that’s when the gifts will stop/ceased.

Verse 8, “but whether there be prophecies, they shall fail” they shall fail-καταργέω/katargeó meaning to be inoperative, useless and or abolished; this verbs is referring to the noun, prophecies.

Also, “whether there be knowledge, it shall vanish away” it shall vanish away is a verb that refers to the Knowledge; it is the same verb meaning as above, katargeó, that is, knowledge will be rendered inoperative or abolished

However, “We know in part, and we prophesy in part,” Prophecies and the general knowledge of those prophecies, will still come to pass, even though the Lord/the perfect has come/returned.
The difference is we/the saints will no longer be tongues speaking, prophesying nor giving any knowledge when Christ returns.

The past prophets prophecies will still come to pass, in that time, Jesus Christ’s Return.
For example, in the book of Ezekiel chapter 38, the Lord God had returned, and the Lord points out Himself that these things happening was prophesied before in time past: concerning Gog, from the north parts, those with him, a great company.

Ezekiel 38:16 And thou shalt come up against my people of Israel, as a cloud to cover the land; it shall be in the latter days, and I will bring thee against my land, that the heathen may know me, when I shall be sanctified in thee, O Gog, before their eyes.
17 Thus saith the Lord GOD; Art thou he of whom I have spoken in old time by my servants the prophets of Israel, which prophesied in those days many years that I would bring thee against them?

Difference between tongues, from knowledge and prophecies, tongues will stop or cease upon Christ Second Advent; for the saints won’t be speaking in tongues, a foreign language and or a tongue giving for knowledge; the saints will have that Perfect one, Christ; however, past prophecies and the Knowledge of that prophecy will be in effect.
The saints who prophecy or by God’s Spirit was given Knowledge will have none of these gifts for it will be inoperative or abolished: for a saint/prophet to utilize.

#4 what is the significance of the transitive verb παύσονται?

The transitive verb παύσονται refers to tongues, the noun.
In verse 9 of 1 corinthians 13, the verb there, accordant to Bible hub Strongs concordance definition, to stop (transitively or intransitively), i.e. Restrain, quit, desist, come to an end -- cease, leave, refrain.
The verb παύσονται means they shall cease, relates to the tongues which is the noun or substantive: it is the direct object of the transitive verb, they shall cease, is referring to.

#5 What does ἐκ μέρους mean?
According to Bible hub NAS exhaustive concordance, V. Adverbial phrases: #3 “of the measure or standard: ἐκ μέρους, so that each is a part of the whole, Meyer at the passage; in part, partly, 1 Corinthians 13:9ff; ἐκ μέτρου”

“So that each is a part of the whole” the in part, part meaning a portion or share, is the knowledge or prophesy that comprises the whole.
The whole deals with Jesus Christ which knowledge or prophesies point to Him, hence, He is the Perfect or the teleios: having reached its end or goal.
Those other parts are inoperative or abolished; the Lord is the consummated goal of prophecies, knowledge, Scriptures for all these parts points to Him. John 5:39,46,47 & Luke 24:25, 26,27:
John 5:39 “Search the scriptures; for in them ye think ye have eternal life: and they are they which testify of me.”
46 For had ye believed Moses, ye would have believed me: for he wrote of me.
47 But if ye believe not his writings, how shall ye believe my words?

Luke 24: 25 Then he said unto them, O fools, and slow of heart to believe all that the prophets have spoken:
26 Ought not Christ to have suffered these things, and to enter into his glory?
27 And beginning at Moses and all the prophets, he expounded unto them in all the scriptures the things concerning himself.

#6 How should “out of” be translated?
1 Corinthians 13:9 translation is fine how it reads.